# how to change the background image using javascript and keyword this

Tags: javascript, html, url, background, this

why doesn't the commented statement work

HTML CODE:

```
<img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)">
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
function upDate(previewPic){
  var x=document.getElementById('image');

  //x.style.background="url(previewPic.src)";//why doesn't this work while the next statement works
  x.style.background="url('"+previewPic.src"')";
}
```

Comment: `previewPic.src` is "hard-coded" into the string, and since it's not a valid image URL, it does not work... By using your second example, you use string concatenation, which evaluates the value of the variable. That is not the case in the first one

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using getElementbyId when your class doesn't have an id of image (at least in the sample you provided). Either add the id or select by the class or tag name

Answer (score 0):

In your code `"url(previewPic.src)"` is full string that's why it doesn't work. Because your code doesn't know what's previewPic.src

If you want to use a variable inside a string you can use string `concatenation` or `template string` to do so. You can check my code.
You can check details about template literals from [MDN_link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<img onmouseover="upDate(this)" class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" >
</body>
  
  <script>
  
  function upDate(previewPic){
    
    console.log(previewPic.src);
    
    previewPic.style.background=`url(${previewPic.src})`;
    //x.style.background="url('"+previewPic.src"')";
  }
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your examples do not work, the correct way of setting the background image of an HTML tag is to use

```
x.style.background = "url("+previewPic.src+")";
```

note the "+" sign after **previewPic.src**.

explanation:
First: `"url(previewPic.src)";` this changes your previewPic.src into a string literal as its encapsulated in the quotation.

Second: `x.style.background="url('"+previewPic.src"')";` this will not work as you're missing "+" sign after **previewPic.src**

further read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: The OP mentions in his question that the 2nd implementation works.

Comment: I know but I think he may have made a mistake, try it out yourself.